# Apply list of functions to one matrix simultaneously

Tags: r, apply

I have a matrix / data frame with i.e. 10 columns and 1.000.000 rows. Now I want to apply 20 different functions on this matrix and store the results. Each function is like

```
df %>%  group_by(`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`) %>% filter (n()>20 )
```

After that function, I want to save this matrix/data frame into a list, so there should be a list with 20 different matrices/data frames.

I do this in a loop, but that's really slow. I did some tries with `apply`, but couldn't really figure out, what I miss. 
My actual try is:

```
apply(X=df,MARGIN=c(1,2),FUN=function(df) df %>%  group_by(`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`) %>% filter (n()>20 ))
```

It gives an error:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

I can smell that I am not far away from the solution. Can you give me a hint?

Thanks and greetings

Comment: Note that `apply` uses a `for` loop, so you won't get any noticeable speed up with this function. I addition, `apply` works on matrices, so if you have a data.frame with any character vectors, `apply` will build a character matrix and try to work on that. Matrices and data.frames are very different objects.

Comment: Please show the `for` loop version.

Comment: @lmo If I loop for example a column and multiply every value with 2, the loop is like 1000 times slower than an apply function, which multiplys the whole vector with 2. At home I will try the solution from slava-kohut and post my example code

Comment: If it is 1000 times slower, you are doing something weird like growing a vector of values. If all you are doing is multiplying a vector by 2, you can use `myVec2 <- myVec * 2` because this operation is vectorized in R.

Comment: Yes, it was only an example. I think that there is no way grouping a matrix 300 times vectorized, it has to be looped if I get it right. Then I would leave it as it is, with it's cpu parallelization...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Here, `funs` contains names of functions to be applied, and `ml` is the resulting list. Hope this gives you enough hints to achieve what you want. Please provide some data if you need help with your specific problem.

```
funs <- c("sqrt", "log", "exp")

m <- matrix(runif(1.e4), 100, 100)

am <- function(f, m){
  apply(m, MARGIN = 1:2, match.fun(f))
}

ml <- lapply(funs, am, m = m)
```